# Answer only on port 443 (HTTPS)

Tags: ssl, iis-7

I have adjusted IIS to only bind to port 443.  Yet when I go to HTTP (port 80) I get a 404 error which must be being returned by IIS.  I expected "site cannot be reached".  How do I accomplish this?  It is throwing a vulnerability issue.  I do not have any rewrite module in place.

Additionally when I telnet to port 80 on that machine I cannot connect (or it seems that way).

Even when I stop the w3svc service, I get a 404 response when I browse to the server.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html You can stop a site from listening at port 80, but HTTP.sys can still work on that port and respond to requests for other sites or non-IIS applications. If you don't want any response from port 80, block it on Windows Firewall.

Comment: @LexLi that is a good idea.  I hope it doesn't come to that though as I have a ton of servers to manage.   I hope someone comes up with an alternate solution, otherwise I'll go that route.  I think it is just weird that there is any response at all when the service is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Since it response 404 when you go to HTTP(port 80), it seems there is a service running with 80 port. So you can check it by steps below:

**1.** Open "cmd" and run the command `netstat -ano`, it will response a list of active connections.

[image]

**2.** Then find the item which use 80 port and record its "PID".

**3.** Continue to run the command `tasklist|findstr {PID}`, it will show the service which use 80 port. If you are sure this service is not important, you can stop it in "Task Manager".

Of course you can also use the solution provided by Lex Li.

Comment: Ok, so it is still showing port 80 is being bound by w3svc but I cannot find it bound anywhere in the UI.  Only 443.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @JonGlazer Can you see the number of w3svc ? For example, if it is bind with w3svc2, it may be bind with second site in your IIS.